# How to use variables in an "if" statement for algebra?

Tags: python, powershell, algebra

```py
import time

equation = input("type any equation having variables x and y")
text_file = open("testdf.txt", "w+")

for x in range(-1000,1000):
    for y in range(-1000,1000):
        if equation:
             result=x,y
             print(result)
             text_file.write(str(result)+"\n") #for storing results
```

I was making a simple algebra calculator in python but when I was testing it, the file was neglecting equation stored in variable equation. I am making two python files which will save their results and then their common is taken by python to get result. I was able to make powershell create a python file having variable. But Is there any possible way to make a python file able to do this , it would be much better if there is a way to do with single python file.

**File made in powershell (maybe it will make it easy to answer my question):**

```bsh
echo "the format of typing equation is a*x+b*y==c"
echo ""
echo "type ** for ^"
echo ""
echo "there is a limit of -1000 and 1000 so you can't find solution after that"
echo ""
$1= Read-host "type first equation"
$2= Read-host "type second equation"

"text_file = open('result1.txt', 'w+')
import time
for x in range(-1000,1000):
    for y in range(-1000,1000):
        if $1 :
             result=x,y
             text_file.write(str(result)+'\n')       
time.sleep(5)" >> equation1.py



"text_file = open('result2.txt', 'w+')
import time
for x in range(-1000,1000):
    for y in range(-1000,1000):
        if $2 :
             result=x,y
             text_file.write(str(result)+'\n')       
time.sleep(5)" >> equation2.py

start equation1.py
start equation2.py
pause
pause
pause
$objects = @{
  ReferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\result1.txt)
  DifferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\result2.txt)
}
$32 = Compare-Object @objects -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent

$45=$32 | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} | 
              Format-Table -Property InputObject -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders
$45 > common.txt


$3=Get-Content common.txt
$3
timeout /t 1
del equation1.py
del equation2.py
del common.txt
del result1.txt
del result2.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing a second answer because the first one starts to be a bit huge.

You can use the `eval` function and try to protect it following [this guide](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#minimizing-the-security-issues-of-eval).
I wrote a little script that uses this technique, and added a bit of security by checking the input string for potential illegal characters with a regex :

Test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/GW2G4F/1).

```py
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from math import *

from matplotlib import cm

def func3d(x, y):
    global equation
    authorized_globals = {
        'x'     : y,
        'y'     : x,
        'cos'   : cos,
        'sin'   : sin,
        'tan'   : tan,
        'acos'  : acos,
        'asin'  : asin,
        'atan'  : atan,
        'atan2' : atan2,
        'atanh' : atanh,
        'ceil'  : ceil,
        'cosh'  : cosh,
        'sinh'  : sinh,
        'factorial' : factorial,
        'floor' : floor,
        'exp'   : exp,
        'log'   : log,
        'log2'  : log2,
        'log10' : log10,
        'sin'   : sin,
        'sinh'  : sinh,
        'sqrt'  : sqrt,
        'pi'    : pi,
        'e'     : e,
        'tau'   : tau,
        'inf'   : inf,
        'tanh'  : tanh

        }
    return eval(equation, authorized_globals, {})

equation = input("Type any equation having variables x and y")

pattern = re.compile('^([\d\+\-.\/*%()a-z ]*)$')
func3d_vectorized = np.vectorize(func3d)

if pattern.match(equation) is not None:
    x_points = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=100)
    y_points = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=100)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_points, y_points)
    Z = func3d_vectorized(X, Y)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

    # Customize the z axis.
    ax.set_zlim(np.min(Z), np.max(Z))

    # Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.show()
else:
    print("Illegal characters found !")
```

When calling it with the input `sin(sqrt(x**2+y**2))`, the output is the following 3D curve : 
[image: output]

You can then save X, Y, Z in a file to fit your needs ;)

Comment: It was not able to show the answer of a equation having equal to but I changed it to make it able to do in both ways so it solved my problem .Thank you for your help .

Answer (score -1):

## First solutution

You may use the `eval()` method, used to interpret a string as python code.
Be careful with this ! Using this method will allow anyone to do whatever they want with your program and with the rights it has on your computer.

[eval() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

## Second solution

Another way to do this would be to rewrite your own calculator.
I wrote for you the following code, that allows you to compute an expression. You can modify it to accept `x` and `y` parameters, and make them change.

```py
import re


def add(a,b):
    return a + b

def substract(a,b):
    return a-b

def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b

def devide(a,b):
    return a/b

def euclid(a,b):
    return a//b

def power(a,b):
    return a**b

def modulo(a,b):
    return a%b

SYMBOLS = {
    '/' : devide,
    '//': euclid,
    '*' : multiply,
    '^' : power,
    '%' : modulo,
    '+' : add,
    '-' : substract,
}

order = ['^', '/', '//', '*', '%', '+', '-']

equation = "3.4*2 + 4 - 10 / 5^2" 


regex = '\d*\.\d+|\d+'
numbers = [float(x) for x in re.findall(regex, equation)]
symbols = re.findall('[\+\-\/*%()^]+', equation)



print(symbols)
print(numbers)

for symbol in order:
    present = True
    while present:
        try:
            index = symbols.index(symbol)
            calculation = SYMBOLS[symbol](numbers[index], numbers[index+1])
            numbers.pop(index+1)
            symbols.pop(index)
            numbers[index] = calculation
        except ValueError:
            present = False

print("result : {}".format(numbers[0]))
```

output :

```
['*', '+', '-', '/', '^']
[3.4, 2.0, 4.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.0]
result : 10.4
```

Flaws of this system :

- Really slow
- You need to implement every operation, parenthesis handling, etc

You can go around the "really slow" problem by refactoring my code to do all the calculation at once using the `numpy` module capability to do parralel calculation.

[draw graphs with numpy](https://medium.com/future-vision/plotting-equations-in-python-d0edd9f088c8)

[numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/)

## Third solution

A third way would be to call a calculation API to parse the strings and do the work for you. The problem will be that if you want to have 1000 plots on your graph, you'll do 1000 calls to the API, and get IP banned.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any safer alternative to eval() ?

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I've modified my answer to give you some other solutions